# Google drive sdk app not showing in open with list

Tags: google-drive-api

I have a google drive app. It is setup to be a drive app and the open url is given in the app details.

Everything works well, but for some reason when the user installs the app it is not displayed in the "Open with" list of apps.

the app is setup to use google documents and docx (this is given in the default mime types).

I also had pdf in the mime types and it was working for them I switched it off and it was correctly turned off.

Any idea why an app might not be showing up in the "open with" menu by default?

Please get back to me as this is having a huge impact we are getting a lot of questions from users that are not being able to find the app..we have over 1000 installations already.

The app also has a launch icon setup on the manifest file. I don't supposed this affects it's behaviour on drive?

```
"launch": {
  "web_url": "http://mail.google.com/mail/"
}
```

Best regards,
Joao Garin

Comment: seems like you need to connect the app for it to start working..Is there a way to connect automatically when installing it from Chrome webstore?

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled both the Drive API and the Drive SDK in the Google Developer Console?

See the details on [enable the drive platform](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/enable-sdk) and make sure you have everything configured properly.

Comment: Yes I do have them enabled. the app is working fine in every aspect and has been for quite a while (about 5 months). But when users install the app via the Google chrome webstore it has happended that the app was not "Connected" to Drive. So when going to drive they would still need to click manage apps, find the app and click connect.